# How do I stop update manager trying to downgrade my 3.4 kernel to 3.2?

Tags: kernel, update-manager, downgrade

I installed the 3.4 kernel for hardware support reasons, and everything is working swimmingly.. but UpdateManager keeps prompting me to install the 3.2 kernel again. Is there a way to stop it doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one is downgrading your 3.4 kernel. Update Manager is simply upgrading your existing 3.2 kernel to the newer release. You will still boot 3.4 by default.

It's a good idea to keep stock kernels around, but if you want to stop the above behavior, simply open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-3.2\*
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` will also work

Answer (score 4):

Update Manager only does *one* thing, it *updates* things, it *updates* your repository list and *updates* the packages found in those repositories you have in your sources.

It does not downgrade anything, you get the *update* for Kernel 3.2 because you *have* a 3.2 kernel installed. Now since you installed the 3.4 kernel and don't want to be bothered again for *updates* for the 3.2 version, simply remove the 3.2 packages.

Open Synaptic (if you don't have it install it `sudo apt-get install synaptic`)then search for  "linux 3.2" if you don't get proper results try with "linux image" or "linux headers" adding the version "3.2" and uninstall them.

Voilá! you won't be bothered again with the *upgrade* for 3.2.

Comment: Thanks, seems so obvious when you put it like that! I used aptitude rather than synamptic using `aptitude search linux` and there it was

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation: Using the kernel 3.4.0 because a hardware issue with the stock kernel, and being afraid to install the propossed kernel updates in the update manager.

But like the people is saying here, that update just updates the old kernel, and that's all. That means that your grub will continue booting with your 3.4 kernel like always.

You can update witouth fear.

Answer (score 0):

You could [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the new kernel package. But that would mean you'd get no updates on that either. Assuming the new (3.4) kernel comes form a different repository than the old (3.2), you could try to play with the [apt repository priorities](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) -- favoring the 3.4 over the 3.2. Obviously the current setup is the other way round, or it would not ask you to downgrade (normally, the higher version wins).

You might further look at [this question at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/439910/how-to-reduce-3rd-party-repository-priority-in-apt), which describes a similar topic.

**Edit:** If you didn't install the kernel using a package file, but rather compiled (and installed) it manually -- the packaging system will never know about. So there will be no automatic updates to your new kernel however (unless you apply them manually again). So in this case, you can simply pin the currently installed 3.2 kernel packages, until one of the repositories provides 3.4+ packages you want to use. Remember to update your 3.4 kernel manually in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Update Manager , proposes all sorts of Update , including distribution upgrades too.

The best way in your scenario to avoid the **3.2 Kernel Downgrade** would be to use alternate and back-end method of using **Gnome-terminal** or Command Line Interface[CLI]  for Updating.

Enter these commands,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will search for Updated packages and install them similar to the function of **Update Manager** ,but if Kernel upgrades are found , it will not download and install them , but will provide a message like

> Following packages were not Upgraded.

Whereas upgrading to newer available kernel requires use of

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is actually like a workaround  , since you are using Both the **official repositories provided Kernel and Mainline Kernel**. If you specifically want only this kernel to be present in your system , then refer the [Uri Herrera](https://askubuntu.com/users/4203/uri-herrera) suggestion. But having a **official Stable kernel**  present is always recommended .